# Trying to change column from object to to date time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to change a object column to a date time column.

However, every time I run the code below, I get an *TypeError: "NATType" object is not callable*.

I am assuming that this is due to the blanks in the column but I am not really sure how to resolve it. Removing the rows is not an option here because there are other columns to consider as well.

```
df['jahreskontakt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['jahreskontakt'], errors='ignore')
```

Does anybody have any advice? Thanks in advance.

Explanations:

```
df['jahreskontakt'] #column with yearly contacts by sales team
```

Values that can be found in the column:

- 2014-07-01 00:00:00
- 00:00:00
- ""

Full error: Tried changing between error = coerce or ignore

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most 

recent call last)
<ipython-input-122-9d57805d9290> in <module>()
----> 1 df['jahreskontakt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['jahreskontakt'], errors='coerce')

TypeError: 'NaTType' object is not callable
```

Comment: @MrFuppes thank you, just did so now.

Comment: @MrFuppes yes, the blanks are NaN so rows that are completely empty.

Comment: hm cannot reproduce the error with the example data; pd.to_datetime just returns a datetime series as expected; blanks are converted to `NaT` (tested with pd.__version__ 1.3.5).

Comment: @MrFuppes its weird, I could find very little about this online as it is usually very straightforward. 

I tried running everything again and I get the same error.

Comment: What happens if you use `errors='coerce'`?

Comment: @MrFuppes unfortunately, I get the same error. TypeError: "NATType" object is not callable..

Comment: the error means you're trying to do something like `pd.NaT()` - but I can't reproduce that with `pd.to_datetime`. I'm out of ideas here, just the usual "did you try to turn it off and on again" maybe...

Comment: @MrFuppes thank you. I think I found the error. 

I was using Google Colab - just because I thought its easier to share files, but when I tried this again in a Jupyter notebook it worked...I thought they Colab and Jupyter are the same but apparently not.